# I get error as "Method save does not exist." while updating the data

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5.4

I want to update the record. I use mongo db and php and I am using laravel 5.4. while updating the data I get the error

**BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:**

**Method save does not exist.**

```
public function updatedata()
    {
        $id = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('login2')->where('_id','=',1)->get();
        $id->name = 'Rajesh';
        $id->save();

        //return $id;
    }
```

Comment: use  print_r($id); die;  after $id = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('login2')->where('_id','=',1)->get();   then check what output comes

Comment: Currently, Laravel supports four databases: MySQL, Postgres, SQLite, SQLServer. It is something about this. [More info.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database)

Comment: after using print_r I get error as `FatalThrowableError in mongo.php line 30:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: Laravel supports mongodb. all thing we have to do is the connection and configuration we have to give mongodb

Comment: try to test this in `php artisan tinker`, and see what the $id variable is, because it is apparently not of a type that has a `save` method.
As for support, Laravel 5.4 does not have mongodb support out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the Job! Let me know if it works!

```
public function updatedata()
    {
        $id = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('login2')->where('_id','=',1)->first();
        $id->name = 'Rajesh';
        $id->save();

        //return $id;
    }
```